# Grails custom field name in validation

Tags: java, validation, grails, groovy

I'm using `grails 2.5.1`.

In database I got almost hundred fields(eg: `card_no, card_user, user_name`, ect).

By default, the validation will show error message: `property card_no cannot be null`

However, I'd to change it to: `property Card No cannot be null`, I need to define that error in `message.property`. I got a lot of fields and it takes time to define `error message` for each one.

Is there any possible way to define the `constraints` for that field?

Like: `card_no(nullable: false, range: 0..19, validator: { val, obj -> return 'abc' })`

Then I can easy to use default validation

I tried that code from other post but syntax seems to be error.

Any solutions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't get your question completely. What do you want to achieve? Do you want to make your camelCase field name to title or do you want to define custom validator for fields?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you don't align to the Grails convention to name all properties according to java camel-back-case standard. The property should be named cardNo in Grails. Grails automatically maps property name `cardNo` to the table column `card_no` but if this does not fit your column names you should fix that with a `mapping` section instead.

EDIT: If you follow the convention in the property naming, you can use [i18n](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/i18n.html) to customize the names of the properties. That will also be reflected in the error messages.

Comment: Hi, could you show me the syntax in mapping section? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks but it's not what i'm looking for, because cardNo or card_no doesn't make sense in the error message, What I need is an alternative name Card No of field card_no which displays in message validation, Thanks anyway

Comment: If you follow the conventions, you can use i18n to customize the names of the properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `scaffolding` or using `g:message` for rendering error/validation messages then `overriding` the `message` tag in `g` namespace can achieve what you want.

You do not need to add any custom validator or any messages in message files. All you need to do is create a `TagLib` which extends `ValidationTagLib` and overrides `message` closure.

For example in your particular case if you just want to make the field names more readable in case of validation exceptions, you can do something like following

```
    class ApplicationTagLib extends ValidationTagLib {

        Closure message = { attrs ->
            def error = attrs.error
            if(error && error instanceof FieldError) {
                //arguments[0] should be the field name
                error.arguments[0] = error.arguments[0].capitalize().replaceAll(/([a-z])([A-Z])/, '$1 $2')
            }

            super.message.call(attrs)
        }
    }
```